# assign not updating result value in testbench in EDA playground

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am using EDA Playground with Aldec Riviera simulator, and I have this module here:

```
module alu(input  logic [31:0] a, b,
           input  logic [2:0]  alucontrol,
           output logic [31:0] result,
           output logic        zero);
  
  logic [31:0] condinvb, sum;

  assign condinvb = alucontrol[2] ? ~b : b;
  assign sum = a + condinvb + alucontrol[2];
 
  always_comb
    case (alucontrol[1:0])
      2'b00: result = a & b;
      2'b01: result = a | b;
      2'b10: result = sum;
      2'b11: result = sum[31];
    endcase

  assign zero = (result == 32'b0);
endmodule
```

and my testbench is here:

```
module alu_testbench();
  logic [31:0] a,b;
  logic [2:0] alucontrol;
  logic [31:0] result;
  logic zero, clk;
  
  alu test_alu(a,b,alucontrol);
  
  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd"); $dumpvars(1);
    clk = 0;
    a = 'hdead0000; b = 'h0000beef; alucontrol = 'b010; #1;
    a = 'hc0debabe; b = 'h0000ffff; alucontrol = 'b000; #1;
    a = 'hc0de0000; b = 'h0000babe; alucontrol = 'b001; #1;
    a = 'hc0debabe; b = 'h0000babe; alucontrol = 'b100; #1;
  end
  
  always begin
    #1; clk = ~clk;
  end
endmodule
```

When I run the testbench and look at the generated waveform, I do not see `result` being updated. Instead, it stays as `XXXX_XXXX`. What am I doing wrong in the testbench?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the testbench, you declared the `result` signal, but it is not connected to anything.  You probably intended it to be driven by the `alu` output of the same name.  In that case, you should connect it to the instance:

Change:

```
  alu test_alu(a,b,alucontrol);
```

to:

```
  alu test_alu(a,b,alucontrol,result,zero);
```

Try your code on other simulators on edaplayground; you should get warnings about unconnected ports.

With your code, if you looked inside the `alu` instance, the `result`  signal would not be X.

---

Another equivalent way to code the instance is to use connections by name:

```
alu test_alu (
    .a           (a),
    .b           (b),
    .alucontrol  (alucontrol),
    .result      (result),
    .zero        (zero)
);
```

This makes it easier to avoid common connection errors.